# Appending all text from .txt files into a single cell in a .csv file using Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv, txt

Good evening everyone, I've been using Python for only a few weeks so apologies if my question happens to be too basic. I've read a lot of similar threads here, but I'm stuck on a few points that I'm currently struggling with.

**Context and current task**:
I have a collection of several thousands of pdf files. I already managed to OCR everything removing header/footer and to extract the text. I have a folder with all my text files in UTF-8 format and a .csv file with some metadata (file name, country, year, etc.). Now I'm essentially trying to add the entire body of text from each .txt file into a matching cell of the .csv file that I already have. My idea was to first save the text into a separate .csv file and then to merge the 2 using the filename as ID. The main issue I'm having is that the body of text is being saved over multiple cells in a row instead of being saved into a single cell. I'm also not sure how to include the filename in the final output

**The code I produced so far**:

```
import os
from _csv import writer


# Obtain list of txt files in folder
path = "/Users/dominik/nltk_data/corpora/my_corpus"

for (root, dirs, file) in os.walk(path):
    file_list = []
    for x in file:
        if '.txt' in x:
            file_list.append(x)

print(file_list)


# Set directory
os.chdir(path)


# Loop through files
for x in file_list:
    # Open .txt file and save content
    with open(x, 'r') as input:
        txt_content = input.read()
        # Open .csv file and append previously saved content
        with open('test.csv', 'a') as output:
            writer_obj = writer(output)
            writer_obj.writerow(txt_content)
            output.close()
```

This is is how I would like the final output to look like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1 | All text in file 1 |
| Filename2 | All text in file 2 |
| ... | ... |

However, right now the file name is not included (not sure how to do that) and the text extracted from my .txt files is not saved into a single cell. Instead, each character is stored separately like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Column I | Column J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | n |  | e | x | a | m | p | l | e |

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `writer_obj.writerow()` expects a list, but you're passing it txt_content, which is a string.  So it turns that string into a list of letters, and writes one letter per cell

Try changing it to `writer_obj.writerow([x, txt_content])` and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you, that helped! However, now I notice that the files get truncated. I suppose  that the files exceed the maximum number of characters per cell. Is there any workaround? A different format? Another library?

Comment: Excel silently truncates data it doesn't like.  You're also going to run into troubles in your comma separated values file if your text ever contains a comma.  I'd recommend using any data structure other than excel/csv, JSON for preference, but that's going to change how you handle and present the data downstream so you'll need to experiment to find out what's best for you

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm a little bit more used to a rows by columns visualization. If I try to do this in **pandas** (my understanding is that I can easily convert this into a JSON if necessary at a later stage), will I run into the same problem of text being truncated? Sorry for the newbie question, but switching to a new library is still very time consuming for me and I wanna be sure that I'm learning something that will help me to solve my current problem before investing more time into it.

Comment: Pandas is tremendously powerful, fast, and functional.  It doesn't truncate, reformat, or otherwise mess around with data the way excel does.  It's by far the best package for handling large amounts of data.  It is, however, quite complicated and has a steep learning curve.  It all depends on what you're trying to achieve - why, for example, do you want the entire text of thousands of pdf files in one file?  What do you intend to do with it next?

Comment: For now longitudinal topic modeling and sentiment analysis. At a much later stage, dynamic word embedding. I'm not sure what is the most efficient way to handle the data here. Intuitively, coming from Stata, I tend to always visualize my data as a matrix with a row for every case (each pdf file in this situation) and a column for every variable (country, year, body of text, etc.).